# How to optimize table query speed MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Say there's a table description as below:

```
| spend_daily_level | CREATE TABLE `spend_daily_level` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `system_value` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `checked_value` decimal(16,2) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `spend_daily_level_date_account_id_f38b1186_uniq` (`date`,`account_id`),
  KEY `spend_daily_level_account_id_f6df4f99_fk_account_id` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `spend_daily_level_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |



+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| active        | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_time  | datetime(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_time  | datetime(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date          | date          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| system_value  | decimal(16,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| checked_value | decimal(16,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_id    | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The data in this table is abtained from third party API and saved daily.  I want to optimize this table query but `partition` seems to be not supported with foreign key.

My question is how can I do some optimization in this case as the amount of datas increasing daily?

And there're two main querys I would use:

## 1

```
SELECT `spend_daily_level`.`account_id`, 
       `spend_daily_level`.`sale_leader_id`, 
       SUM(`spend_daily_level`.`system_value`) AS `sum_value` 
FROM `spend_daily_level` 
WHERE `spend_daily_level`.`active` = True 
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `spend_daily_level`.`date`) = 7 
  AND `spend_daily_level`.`date` BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY `spend_daily_level`.`account_id`, 
         `spend_daily_level`.`sale_leader_id`
```

## 2

```
SELECT sale_leader_id, 
       SUM(s.`system_value`) 
FROM `spend_daily_level` s 
WHERE DATE = "2020-05-29"
GROUP BY sale_leader_id
```

Thanks

Comment: Speaking of performance mainly makes sense in the context of running queries against your table.  What are the queries?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your reply, I've updated most used sqls above.

Comment: First query may be optimized by adding an additional column with month number and applying index over [`active`, `month`, `date`]. You can even try to encode `month` and `active` into a signle column to get more perfomance.

Comment: You can try with indexing `active` column and changing date column to timestamp, but it doesn't must to give you much difference.

Comment: Query #1. Replace ```AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `spend_daily_level`.`date`) = 7 AND `spend_daily_level`.`date` BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'``` with ```AND `spend_daily_level`.`date` BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-07-31'```. Test the index by `(active, date)`. Query #2. `spend_daily_level_date_account_id_f38b1186_uniq` is enough. You may try also the index by `(date, sale_leader_id)`.

Comment: @Tajni *You can try with indexing `active` column* makes sense only if above ~95% of rows has `active=false`.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for all your replies above, and what if the data is increasing after several years in speed of `200k` per day? Is `index date` still enough then?

Comment: If 2nd query always selects the data for single day and daily data array size is approximately constant then the query speed depends on the data array growth very low.

Comment: @Akina Does it mean that the `partition` on `date` is always not needed in this situation?

Comment: Does this two queries are the only queries executed over this table (except INSERT of course)? If not then I doubt that partitioning makes sense.

Comment: @Akina Not only these, but the others are with same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second query you'll want

```
create index idx1 on spend_daily_level (date, sale_leader_id, system_value);
```

The first query could benefit from an index starting with `active` or `date` - whichever is more selective. I would simply provide two indexes and see which one is used and which one is not. (The query would benefit much more from an index on `date` of course if it where written `WHERE date BETWEEN DATE '2020-07-01' AND DATE '2020-07-31'` or `WHERE date >= DATE '2020-07-01' AND date < DATE '2020-08-01'`.)

```
create index idx2 on spend_daily_level (date, acitve, sale_leader_id, account_id, system_value);
create index idx3 on spend_daily_level (acitve, date, sale_leader_id, account_id, system_value);
```

Partitions are something rarely needed. You'll want them with billions of rows in the table and working almost only in one partition. I don't think you need them for your database.